# Extract values from a json response in mule flow

Tags: json, mule

I have a json response like this -- 
I want to extract the value of p_ProviderID. 
Please guide me how to do it in a mule flow?

```html
{ 
"category" : "Address",
"status": "SUCCESS",
"result":  {
              "p_ProviderID": 4, 
       "p_NewProvInd": "Exist"
           }
}
```

Comment: I do not know what mule is, but your JSON is definitely incorrect. Wrong quotes, non-quoted strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object" />` and then you can get the value using MEL `#[message.payload.result.p_ProviderID]`

For example, you can get the value of **p_ProviderID** in logger after using `<json:json-to-object-transformer/>` as follow:-

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
<logger message="#[message.payload.result.p_ProviderID]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

For a Json as simple as this, you are better off with JsonPath. A simple expression like this `#[json:result/p_ProviderID]` would give you what you wanted.

P.S.: Mule's support for JsonPath as of 3.5 is quite limited and is not as flexible as Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use Json to Object converter and set return class type to java.util.Map or Java.util.List - in your case this is Map. If you have multiple element of same type in Json you need to use java.util.List